# Is it possible to easily create a Kudu table from a PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-kudu

Ideally the following code snipped would work:

```
import kudu 
from kudu.client import Partitioning

df = … #some spark dataframe 

# Connect to Kudu master server 
client = kudu.connect(host=‘…‘, port=7051)

# infer schema from spark dataframe
schema = df.schema 

# Define partitioning schema 
partitioning = Partitioning().add_hash_partitions(column_names=['key'], num_buckets=3) 

# Create new table 
client.create_table('dev.some_example', schema, partitioning)
```

But the client.create_table expects a kudu.schema.Schema and not a struct from the dataframe. However in Scala you can do this (from https://kudu.apache.org/docs/developing.html):

```
kuduContext.createTable(
"dev.some_example", df.schema, Seq("key"),
new CreateTableOptions()
    .setNumReplicas(1)
    .addHashPartitions(List("key").asJava, 3))
```

Now I was wondering if I can do the same with PySpark without manually defining each column with the kudu schema builder?

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote myself a helper function to convert  a PySpark Dataframe schema into a kudu.schema.Schema I hope this helps somebody. Feedback is appreciated!

A side note, you might want to add or edit the data type mapping.

```
import kudu
from kudu.client import Partitioning
def convert_to_kudu_schema(df_schema, primary_keys):
    builder = kudu.schema.SchemaBuilder()
    data_type_map = {
        "StringType":kudu.string,
        "LongType":kudu.int64,
        "IntegerType":kudu.int32,
        "FloatType":kudu.float,
        "DoubleType":kudu.double,
        "BooleanType":kudu.bool,
        "TimestampType":kudu.unixtime_micros,
    }

    for sf in df_schema:
        pk = False
        nullable=sf.nullable
        if (sf.name in primary_keys): 
            pk = True
            nullable = False

        builder.add_column(
            name=sf.name,
            nullable=nullable,
            type_=data_type_map[str(sf.dataType)]
        )
    builder.set_primary_keys(primary_keys)
    return builder.build()
```

You can call it like this:

```
kudu_schema = convert_to_kudu_schema(df.schema,primary_keys=["key1","key2"])
```

I am still open for a more elegant solution. ;)

Comment: This works only if the primary keys are in order in the df.schema already.